# Error in using Maybe types in CLEAN

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, clean-language

i'm a newbie with functional programming and CLEAN. I have a few functions and i get error in one, and i cannot figured out why.
(I tagged that with Haskell because it's very similar to CLEAN.)

My module:

```
module Prac

combine :: (Maybe a) (Maybe [a]) -> Maybe [a]
combine Nothing _ = Nothing
combine _ Nothing = Nothing
combine (Just d) (Just [x:xs]) = Just [d, x:xs]

sequence :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
sequence [Just x:xs] =  combine  (Just x)  Just[xs]
```

It fails at the sequence definition:

```
 Type error [Prac.icl,32,sequence]: near combine : cannot unify types:
 [v8] -> Maybe [v4]
 Maybe [v5]
```

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Seems like you need to enclose `Just[xs]` in parenthesis in the last line.

Comment: yes, i tried, and it fails, what i dont understand. Type error [Prac.icl,32,sequence]:"argument 1 of list constructor" cannot unify types:
 v9
 [Maybe v9]

Comment: yes, combine works fine. combine (Just 1) (Just [2, 3]) == Just [1, 2, 3]

Comment: If this works then I am not sure about the syntax of CLEAN - I answered with something that will work in Haskell - maybe you can try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work in Haskell:

```
combine :: Maybe a -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
combine Nothing _ = Nothing
combine _ Nothing = Nothing
combine (Just d) (Just xs) = Just (d:xs)

sequence :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
sequence [] = Just []
sequence (a:xs) =  combine  a (sequence xs)
```

but I'm not sure if it does what you want:

```
λ> sequence [Just 1, Just 3, Just 4]
Just [1,3,4]

λ> sequence [Just 1, Nothing, Just 4]
Nothing

λ> sequence []
Just []
```

ok, I have found a [translation scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_(programming_language)) - but no gurantee as I don't have a way to test it rigth now

```
sequence :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
sequence [] = Just []
sequence [x:xs] =  combine x (sequence xs)
```

not sure about the empty list and the signature though - sorry

Anyway if you can reuse the idea that you just combine the head of the given list with the recursive computated sequence of the tail you should be fine

### this works for me using clean

So I just downloaded the IDE, made a project, added one module:

```
module seq

:: MayBe a = Just a | Nothing

Start = sequence [Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]

combine Nothing _ = Nothing
combine _ Nothing = Nothing
combine (Just d) (Just xs) = Just [d:xs]

sequence [] = Just []
sequence [x:xs] =  combine x (sequence xs)
```

compiled this, updated the project and did run it - and here this works

Comment: "Run time error, rule 'sequence' in module does not match"

Comment: @GaborToth I cannot help here to much - in Haskell there is a `sequence` in the prelude you have to hide `import Prelude hiding (sequence)` or you have to give another name to it - no clue if this is different in CLEAN - or maybe you have to give the compiler some clue that this is a recursive function (for example you have to do so in F#) - or a combination of these two

Comment: @GaborToth based on the Wiki page it's not the recursion so I would first try to give it another name in case there too is a sequence in your prelude or StdEnv or whatever it's called

Comment: Thank you Carsten for your time, its really good! (I missed in the combine's definition one thing!)

Comment: @GaborToth no problem - glad I could help - and now I learned about clean too ;)

Comment: In Clean, you can also simply `import StdMaybe` (you have to add `$CLEANHOME/lib/StdLib` to the include path) to get the `Maybe` type along with `isNothing`, `fromJust` and possibly other functions.